# How can I join list elements into particular other elements

Tags: python, list

hello everybody, it's my first post:)

I have a small script which creating me a list with occurrence of some data: output is a list, print of that looks like this:

```
2018-06-07,thingA,100173 
2018-06-07,thingB,35277
2018-06-08,thingA,87599
2018-06-08,thingB,35311 
2018-06-09,thingA,94371 
2018-06-09,thingB,45330 
2018-06-10,thingA,104483 
2018-06-10,thingB,51726
```

I'm trying to convert it to such view:

```
2018-06-07,100173,35277
2018-06-08,87599,35311
2018-06-09,94371,45330
2018-06-10,104483,51726
```

So I would like to joins rows with same date to one row with thingA on second position and thingB on third. It looks easy but I don't know how to bite it.

My code counts occurance of things A and B depends of date:

> [...'2018-06-09,thingA', '2018-06-09,thingB'...]

```
yyyy = [[x,lista.count(x)] for x in set(lista)]
yyyy.sort()
for x in yyyy:
        x  = x[0] + "," + str(x[1])
```

Kind Regards,
Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an O(n) solution, you can use `collections.defaultdict` on a list of lists `L`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for date, thing, num in L:
    d[date].append(num)

res = [[date, *nums] for date, nums in d.items()]
```

**Result:**

```
print(res)

[['2018-06-07', 100173, 35277],
 ['2018-06-08', 87599, 35311],
 ['2018-06-09', 94371, 45330],
 ['2018-06-10', 104483, 51726]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
data = [['2018-06-07', 'thingA', '100173 '], ['2018-06-07', 'thingB', '35277'], ['2018-06-08', 'thingA', '87599'], ['2018-06-08', 'thingB', '35311 '], ['2018-06-09', 'thingA', '94371 '], ['2018-06-09', 'thingB', '45330 '], ['2018-06-10', 'thingA', '104483 '], ['2018-06-10', 'thingB', '51726']]
new_data = [[a, *[i[-1] for i in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
print('\n'.join(','.join(i) for i in new_data))
```

Output:

```
2018-06-07,100173,35277
2018-06-08,87599,35311 
2018-06-09,94371,45330 
2018-06-10,104483,51726
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ajax1234, much appreciated.

I needed to do some changes to prepare proper data and finally I used your help:

```
new_data = [[a, [i[-1] for i in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(yyyy_new, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0]$
for i in new_data:
        isplit = i[1]
        print(i[0],isplit[0],isplit[1])
```

Thanks!